How get data from iCloud onto iPhone
I have an iPhone 14 running iOS 17.1.1.
I have disabled most iCloud stuff for my iPhone, but I just noticed that iCloud Drive under Storage in Settings comes with a note saying that files stored in iCloud Drive (and probably data used by certain third party apps) are downloaded on-demand. I want those files on my iPhone. If I turn off iCloud Drive syncing, then they won't be on my phone and would instead be deleted from my phone. How do I fix this?

Can you edit your post to add a screen shot of the specific setting you intend to toggle so we can understand exactly what your setup looks like?

I'm not 100% sure of your question but the Files app on your phone has iCloud drive listed. Open it and you will see all your files that are in the cloud. If you select 'on my phone' you will see those that are in your phone. Why do you want to turn off iCloud synching ? Just toggle off things like photos if you like that can take up all your allowed iCloud data.Leave 'iCloud Drive' toggled on.I only synch things like notes,iCloud Drive,reminders etc.....nothing data 'heavy'.
